# wso2 identity server dashboard forgot password/forgot username not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I followed the below steps to enable password recovery using email notification.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Password+Recovery

When I click forgot password button on dashboard login page, it asks for username and after that throw below error

**Code : 20017
Message :Notification based password recovery is not enabled**

I checked code in github and found property recovery.notification.password.enable is used but could not locate in any config file or any documentation. I am using WSO2IS 5.3.0.
How can i enable password recovery through end user dashboard if not mentioned in above mentioned steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you are following the old and deprecated method. The steps for new APIs are available at the [REST API Guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/apidocs/account-recovery/index.html#configuring-rest-api), It is also linked from the section "Password recovery using REST APIs" in the page you referred.

What you need to do is enable the `Notification Based Password Recovery Enabled` at the Resident Identity Provider configuration at management console and optionally set the expiry time for notifications.

Comment: thanks @pulasthi7 for the answer. Dont know why this is not mentioned in the password recovery steps.